# Invalid configuration file

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I wanna install this theme [theme](http://www.zerocarts.com/586/bicycle-free-prestashop-themes.html.) but I get "Invalid configuration file"

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop themes for import/autoinstallation should be packed by another way, zip file must contain: `themes/your-theme-folder/` and `Config.xml` file where described which modules have to be enabled/disbaled etc.

In your case solution is:

1. Unpack zip into shop /themes/ folder.
2. In backoffice `Preferences -> Themes` at the bottom `Create new theme`, set theme name and **name of folder that was unpacked from zip** in your case there will be `bikecycle_theme`.
3. Then follow next steps, you can ignore modules stage for now etc.

As result, after you will press "Finish" button, new theme will be installed.