# Prestashop theme not detected

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm new to Prestashop development. The first thing I've tried is to create a new theme copying the default theme directory in Prestashop 1.6. The problem I have is that, once created, the theme is not detected by Prestashop: is like the directory wasn't there.

If I create a new theme from the admin panel and replace the directory content with the same files, it works ok.

What should I do to make Prestashop detect my theme? I haven't found any information about it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered on similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178547/invalid-configuration-file/33186384#33186384), there are two ways to solve your issue *through backoffice*

- Copy default theme in `Preferences -> Theme` press `Add new theme`
  button and then at the bottom `Create new theme` + choosing `Copy missing files from existing theme`.

OR if you already copied theme dir/files by FTP

- Same steps, but without copy missed files (of course if you have no
  missed files) and just put correct new dir name in `Name of the theme's directory`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the way it is done - Copying the default theme.

There could be several reasons for that:

- Have you changed the name of the copied folder?
- Did you use only a single lowercase word as a name?
- Did you copy it to the /themes folder?

Here is additonaly info after the copying to do some cleanup: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+your+own+theme

Also it is perfectly fine to create a copy of the default theme from the backend. You can find instructions here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Laying+the+Theme's+Foundations#LayingtheTheme'sFoundations-Standingontheshouldersofgiants:copyingthedefaulttheme

Comment: I did all of the above. The folder name is "mitema" (I've tried other names) and it's placed in /var/www/themes (the same folder as default-bootstrap). It's a shared folder of a vagrant machine, but I think it doesn't matter: from the point of view of the web server is like a normal folder. If I insert manually a row in ps_themes with the info of that theme, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are using Prestashop 1.7 or higher and is facing the same problem when copying the [Starter Theme](https://github.com/PrestaShop/StarterTheme), I recommend you to check if you actually have a `themes/your_theme/config/theme.yml` configuration file because the one that is loaded by default is a `theme.dist.yml` so Prestashop won't recognize it.